# Julia Graphplot error "MethodError: no method matching get_adjacency_matrix(::SimpleDiGraph{Int64})"

Tags: julia, julia-plots, graphplot

I am using the following code in Julia v1.6 to plot a graph:

```
graphplot(metanetwork1, method=:chorddiagram, markersize=3, nodeshape=:rect, linecolor=:lightgrey)
```

where metanetwork1 is a {56, 445} directed simple Int64 graph

I am getting the following error that is getting 0 google results:

```
MethodError: no method matching get_adjacency_matrix(::SimpleDiGraph{Int64})
```

I have no idea what this could mean or how to resolve. The error is coming from the GraphRecipes package in the file graphs.jl [Output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cBEk.png).

Comment: Where is your `graphplot` function from? https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/GraphPlot.jl seems to use `gplot` for its function's name. Please post the full stacktrace when reporting error messages, as that makes it much easier to figure out where the actual problem is.

Comment: I'm not sure the source of the graphplot function, but the error is coming from GraphRecipes package graph.jl file

Comment: Please paste the full error output, including the `Stacktrace`, which will give us a lot more information to go on. Also useful would be the versions of the packages, with `]status Graphs GraphRecipes` in the REPL.